# Javascript form calculating multiple lines & pro rata

Tags: javascript, forms

Thanks in advance:
My membership form needs to add together a couple of lines of fees : so a start up fee + admin fee + (1week of cost+remaining number of days of cost in the week of purchase)
depending on the type of membership that is selected.
I would like to show the amounts in fields, on separate lines for the user to see.

The start up fee and admin fee are known costs $99 and $49. 
1 week costs=$10.99. 
So the mathematical formula in the brackets would be ( if purchased on a sat) $10.99+(10.99*6)/7
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated - I'm in the midst of learning javascript - but I'm just not able to tackle this type of complex calculation as yet. 
- In order to get today's date I thought I would need an onload get date  so I have done that but I really just need it in the code as an integer for the pro rata calculation.
here is a link to the html file so far: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10839148/Weds.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The week start on Sunday so use an array to redefine your values

```
function myDateFunction()
{
  var date = new Date();
  var today = date.getDay();
  var daily = 10.99/7;
  var days = [1, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2];

  // select the tag with the the id Amount
  var x = document.getElementById('Amount');

  // insert the value into the input
  x.value = parseFloat(99 + 49 + (daily * days[today])+10.99).toFixed(2)

}
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/ezuqos/1/edit)

Comment: Sorry...I'm not sure how to implement what you have given me - where do I put what?

Comment: I need the day of the week that the user will be making the purchase so I can use it in the calculation of the pro rata amount which is the : (10.99*day of the week/7) - in this example 6 does mean sat and gives the correct mathematical answer - but I do understand that js starts on a sunday so I guess I would have to include that in my code with a -1 somehow...

Comment: Yeah that looks great! Except I'm trying to work out why you have the minus sign in front of the bracket in the total amount... I think I need to clarify that the pro rata calculation is actually for 2 weeks-the remainder of the current week plus the entire next week - bc then they will get their fortnightly membership deducted after this initial purchase - hope that makes sense!

Comment: I edited again, I now calculate the daily pricing and multiply it by the number of days remaining starting from today, and I suppose the week payment start on monday.

Comment: cool excellent - you're a legend - would you be able to tell me how i transfer the js you have created into my file? I can't use a separate js file for this website I need to put all code in html...Thankyou so much for your time!

Comment: I was hoping to feed the amounts into separate input fields: admin fee, start up and pro rata amount and then total all in total field - can you explain how to do that?

Comment: look at my code, it self-explanatory, to do the same on other input select an other tag using the id

Comment: ok I'll give it a go - I also need to set up some if statements I think bc I have two memberships - A costs= 99+49+Pro rata and B costs=49+prorata and make the calculation switch to the correct membership accordingly